# Excel Formula with if statements and calculations

Tags: excel, formulas

Need assistance on a formula that contains IF statements and calculations.

Manual Data:

```
                 M      |     E
   Army        $42.65       $5.30
   Air Force   $39.59       $21.51
   Navy        $39.99       $5.06
   Marines     $28.59       $5.29
```

Lines of Accounting

```
 US Navy: 17**20142014
 Army:    21**20152015
 AF:      57**20162016
```

See attached spreadsheet.

- If column A equals "E "and the first two digits contain "17" for Navy then multiply the number in column C by $5.06 (see above cost for Navy under header E).
- If column A equals "M "and the first two digits contain "17" then multiply the number in column C by $39.99 (see above cost for Navy under header M).
- If column A equals "M "and the first digit contains "2" for Coast Guard then multiply the number in column C by $39.99 (see above cost for Navy under header M).

I need one large formula that contains the IF statement and calculations for the data listed above that I can place in column E of the attached spreadsheet.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should check this as I have filled in with guesses what you did not mention  (eg that `97*...` is for `Marines`). Also I have not included any error trapping:

```
=C2*INDEX(Tarry,IF(LEFT(B2,2)="21",2,IF(LEFT(B2,2)="57",3,IF(OR(LEFT(B2,2)="2*",LEFT(B2,2)="17"),4,5))),IF(A2="E",3,2))
```

Assumes `Occurrences` is in C1 and that you have a Named Range of `Tarry` that is in effect your 'Manual Data'.